How to stop showing bottom statusline when lualine is enabled?
I have vim.opt.laststatus = 0 in my config, but it only works when lualine is disabled. I did a bunch of looking up and tried the following: require('lualine').setup({ options = { globalstatus = true }}), as well putting vim.go.laststatus = 0 in options and in my config. The only difference I noticed with those is that it would go from showing some text in the statusline, to still showing the statusline just with no text.
The only thing that works is by writing the commands set laststatus=0 or lua vim.opt.laststatus=0 after nvim launches. When I omit all settings of laststatus in my config and do verbose set laststatus after starting nvim up with nvim -V1, it shows nothing. It mentions lua when I don't omit them.
